# Snowflake - unsupported subquery type

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake but I have some basic knowledge in SQl.

I am trying to run this SQL in snowflake but am met with some errors `"unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated"` which I believe is caused by the last statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_INFO I 
LEFT JOIN MAP1
    ON MAP1.VCODE = I.ID AND MAP1.VTYPE = 1
LEFT JOIN MASTER1
    ON MASTER1.SCODE = MAP1.SCODE
    AND MASTER1.TYPE = MAP1.TYPE
JOIN MAP2
    ON MAP2.SCODE = MASTER1.SCODE
    AND MAP2.TYPE = MASTER1.TYPE
LEFT JOIN PRI 
    ON PRI.CODE = MAP2.VCODE AND PRI.ITEM = 754
LEFT JOIN INFO IN_1 
    ON IN_1.CODE = CASE WHEN MAP2.VCODE = 53215 THEN 15623 ELSE MAP2.VCODE END
LEFT JOIN INFO IN_2 
    ON IN_2.CODE = (SELECT CODE FROM INFO WHERE ID = PRI.VALUE)
```

When I try using CTE, I get the error `"Invalid Identifier CTE.CODE"`

```sql
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT INFO.CODE 
    FROM P 
    LEFT JOIN INFO 
        ON INFO.ID = P.VALUE
)
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_INFO I 
LEFT JOIN MAP1
    ON MAP1.VCODE = I.ID
    AND M1.VTYPE = 1
LEFT JOIN MASTER1
    ON MASTER1.SCODE = MAP1.SCODE
    AND MASTER1.TYPE = MAP1.TYPE
JOIN MAP2
    ON MAP2.SCODE = MASTER1.SCODE
    AND MAP2.TYPE = MASTER1.TYPE
LEFT JOIN PRI 
     ON PRI.CODE = MAP2.VCODE 
     AND PRI.ITEM = 754
LEFT JOIN INFO IN_1 
     ON IN_1.CODE = CASE 
         WHEN MAP2.VCODE = 53215 THEN 15623 ELSE MAP2.VCODE END
LEFT JOIN INFO IN_2
     ON IN_2.CODE = CTE.CODE
```

I need help in identifying what exactly went wrong and the approach I could take to resolve this issue.

Comment: Don't have Snowflake online to test with, but could something like rewriting the subquery as `(SELECT MAX(CODE) FROM INFO WHERE ID = PRI.VALUE)` work?

Comment: the last line should be something like:
`LEFT JOIN CTE ON I_1.CODE=CTE.CODE`

Answer (score 0):

You first block of SQL refers to `m1` which is never aliased, and `pr1`, so lets ignore that (but it will make the SQL not run)

So to do this SQL without the correlated sub-query problem is:

I have written the CTE this way, as your original sub-select assumed there was only one code per id, and this was I have hard coded this fact. And it also implies if this is not true you are getting a almost random value of code, but if there are many, it will not choose the null one.

```
WITH cte_1 AS (
    SELECT id, max(code) as code FROM info GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT *
FROM table_info AS i 
LEFT JOIN map1
    ON map1.vcode = i.id and m1.vtype = 1
LEFT JOIN master1
    ON master1.scode = map1.scode
    AND master1.type = map1.type
JOIN MAP2
    ON map2.scode = master1.scode
    AND map2.type = master1.type
LEFT JOIN p 
    ON p.code = map2.vcode and pri.item = 754
LEFT JOIN info AS in_1 
    ON in_1.code = CASE WHEN map2.vcode = 53215 THEN 15623 ELSE map2.vcode END
LEFT JOIN cte_1 AS c
    ON c.id = pri.value
LEFT JOIN info AS in_2
    ON in_2.code = cte_1.code
```

The

```
CASE WHEN map2.vcode = 53215 THEN 15623 ELSE map2.vcode END
```

in snowflake can be written

```
IFF(map2.vcode = 53215, 15623 , map2.vcode)
```

which is a little smaller, but they are the same code.

### Running Code:

So with a lot of fake data in some CTE's

```
WITH table_info(id) as (
    select * from values
    (1)
), map1(vcode, vtype, scode, type) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 1, 10, 11)
), master1(scode, type) as (
    select * from values
    (10, 11)
), map2(vcode, scode, type) as (
    select * from values
    (100, 10, 11)
), p(value, code, item) as (
    select * from values
    (600, 100, 754)
), info(id, code, item) as (
    select * from values
    (600, 100, 754)
),
--WITH 
cte_1 AS (
    SELECT id, max(code) as code FROM info GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT *
FROM table_info AS i 
LEFT JOIN map1
    ON map1.vcode = i.id and map1.vtype = 1
LEFT JOIN master1
    ON master1.scode = map1.scode
    AND master1.type = map1.type
JOIN MAP2
    ON map2.scode = master1.scode
    AND map2.type = master1.type
LEFT JOIN p AS pri
    ON pri.code = map2.vcode and pri.item = 754
LEFT JOIN info AS in_1 
    ON in_1.code = CASE WHEN map2.vcode = 53215 THEN 15623 ELSE map2.vcode END
LEFT JOIN cte_1 AS c
    ON c.id = pri.value
LEFT JOIN info AS in_2
    ON in_2.code = c.code;
```

The SQL works with some heave alias assignment/assumptions. But gives:

| ID | VCODE | VTYPE | SCODE | TYPE | SCODE_2 | TYPE_2 | VCODE_2 | SCODE_3 | TYPE_3 | VALUE | CODE | ITEM | ID_2 | CODE_2 | ITEM_2 | ID_3 | CODE_3 | ID_4 | CODE_4 | ITEM_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 10 | 11 | 10 | 11 | 100 | 10 | 11 | 600 | 100 | 754 | 600 | 100 | 754 | 600 | 100 | 600 | 100 | 754 |

### Side Notes:

`MAP2` is joined currently off `MASTER1` values, but those `MASTER1` are already set the same as `MAP1` values, you could make `MAP2` hang off `MAP1` which might improve performance, as `MASTER1` is then a left join. But that would mean if the LEFT JOIN of MASTER1 fails MAP2 might still LEFT JOIN, where as you have it, those values are only present if MASTER1 joined, and interestingly MAP2 is a inner join, so if MAP2 fails the whole chain fails. Which all implies it's working how you want.

Comment: Thanks for the ans! the question has been edited for m1 and pri. made a mistake on the table alias but your assumtion is correct